# JQuery and PHP Cookies

Tags: php, jquery, cookies

Let's say I make a cookie using jQuery's Cookie Plugin:

```
$.cookie('Cookie', "Cookie Value", 1);
```

Can I read it using php with:

```
echo $_COOKIE["Cookie"];
```

Comment: You could have tested this quicker than it took you to create this question

Comment: Well see I have a page using echo "Cookie is" . $_COOKIE["Cookie"]; and nothing has echoed

Comment: @phil I just tested and can confirm this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.

The cookie is sent back with every HTTP GET or POST to the server made from the domain/path the cookie is set to, until it expires.