# Get value when an html link is clicked

Tags: php, javascript, anchor

Is it possible to get the value of the text in an anchor tag when the link is clicked? e.g
if you have `<a href="#">Tables</a>`
is it possible to retrieve the value "Tables" in a variable like a session variable and use it across your pages?
I have several categories of items(which are links) and i want to be able to get the value of any category clicked and use it pull products listed in that category from my database.
Thanks.

EDIT:
This what i tried
   `<a href="#" onclick= "<?php $_SESSION[value] = "Table" ?>">Table</a>`
But didn't get the value.
Apologies, should have posted it earlier

Comment: Yes, it is possible..

Comment: ok can you guide me on how to go about it?

Comment: You have already asked a number of questions here. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Let's make a deal: you provide your code, and we'll provide specific answers on how to adapt your code to meet your needs.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins wow the negative votes came in so fast. Have edited it. Sorry should've posted it earlier

Comment: You can use jquery to retrieve the values of the clicked links, saving the values in cookies and retrieve those values from a php file

Comment: @RobertRozas To the best of my knowledge, jQuery-created cookies are not accessible by PHP. Can you provide documentation to the contrary?

Comment: @George Cummins ....here is an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086989/jquery-and-php-cookies

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As posted, your code does not submit so your PHP is never processed:

```
<a href="#"
```

When you have "#" as the href value, no new request is submitted. However, you can modify your anchor to submit the category back to your PHP script like this:

```
<a href="yourscript.php?category=Table">Table</a>
```

Then in `yourscript.php` you can read the value using $_GET:

```
$selected_category = $_GET['category']; // Get 'Table'
```

To set the value in your session, first be sure that you have started your session near the top of your script:

```
session_start();
```

then save the value like this:

```
$_SESSION['selected_category'] = $_GET['category'];
```

Comment: Thanks but i get the error message "undefined index category".

Comment: @dhani You will need to make sure your code matches your input. If you get the error while trying to do `$_GET['category']` ensure that your link is providing `category` as a parameter name: `<a href="yourscript.php?category=Table">`

Comment: The parameters are fine. I restarted the server. Though the error still came up initially, the output was perfect. Thanks a bunch. I just wish i didn't acquire so many negative votes in one night..lol

Comment: @dhani you're learning, it's all that matters. some people are going to go around down-voting but don't let it discourage you from asking... !

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you could try to attach an 'id' or 'class' to it and add an event handler to to that id/class.

With javascript looking something like:

```
$('<your link id>').click(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault()
    var content = $(this)[0].innerHTML;
    window.location = '//<your site here>/<php page>?category=' + content;
}
```

I apologize for my mix and match JavaScript/jQuery.

Then you can look for in PHP using

```
$category = $_GET('category');
```

May be worth it to escape user specified data if you plan on doing lookups with it.