# php - getting value when clicked and using in sql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a .php file that prints the results of a query, I want to link the id to another page and use the chosen id to perform another query.
My first file has something like:

```
<a href = 'npage.php?id = $value'>$value</a>
```

I tried doing like told here: 
[Get value when an html link is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16530535/get-value-when-an-html-link-is-clicked)
but it does not work.
In npage.php i have

```
<?php
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['sid'] = $_GET['id'];
 $sid = $_GET['id'];
?>
```

And then i am trying to use it in a query like this:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM Table HAVING id = $sid");
```

But got no results. It seems that $sid is NULL.
Thanks.

Comment: What is the actual `href` value being rendered when the first page loads?

Comment: This is open to SQL injections and depending on the value that may be your current problem. You should use parameterized queries. You can see what a variable is with `var_dump`. You can get the error response from it with http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php.

Comment: my first page creates a table using a mysql query, so $value is on the result of the query.  This seems to be working, cause when i click in $value = 1 of my table i get localhost/npage.php?id=1.

Comment: `npage.php?id = $value` there shouldn't be spaces in there, for one thing.

Comment: and why `HAVING id = $sid`? you should use `WHERE` instead, not `HAVING`. It does work but there's no use for it really.

Comment: what does `var_dump($_GET);` output, when adding it to the top of npage.php ? Is there an id key?

Comment: *"My first file has something like:

`<a href = 'npage.php?id = $value'>$value</a>`"* - We need to know "exactly" how that's used. Question's unclear for quite a few reasons.

Comment: @Fred-ii- While `Having` is quite unusual it is still valid SQL in MySQL

Comment: Thanks  a lot, i missed a space. Now it works.

Comment: @Iarwa1n yes I know thanks, which is why I edited my comment before you pinged me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> *"npage.php?id = $value there shouldn't be spaces in there, for one thing. – Fred -ii- 4 mins ago"*
>
> *"Thanks a lot, i missed a space. Now it works. – Rael"*

as stated in comments by myself

you have spaces in these

```
<a href = 'npage.php?id = $value'>$value</a>
```

you need to remove them

```
<a href = 'npage.php?id=$value'>$value</a>
```

Also as stated in comments by others, your code is open to an SQL injection; use a prepared statement:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Answer (score 0):

apage.php:

```
<?php
$value = 123;
echo "<a href='npage.php?id=$value'>$value</a>";
```

npage.php:

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
echo "Received ID: $id";
```