# how to fetch cookie via jquery in codeigniter?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, cookies

iam debugging an application which sets cookie via jquery.

> $.cookie("cookie_name",'s',{ path: '/'});

how can i fetch the cookie from codeigniter.?

> $this->input->cookie('cookie_name', TRUE);

is not returning anything. please help.

Comment: @dude, it may give some idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086989/jquery-and-php-cookies

Answer (score 1):

Check you have loaded `cookie helper` like,

```
$this->load->helper('cookie');
```

before using it.

If you loaded it then try this `print_r($_COOKIE);` to check whether your `cookie` is set or not.

Read http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/cookie_helper.html

Comment: cookie library is already loaded. the problem is i suppose codeigniter not fetching thw cookie set by jquery.

Comment: And what about `print_r($_COOKIE);`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [this](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) jquery plugin there is also brief documentation how to use it.
by this you create, delete and edit cookie with jquery itself .

Also refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery) answer and on server side you can use normal codeigniter cookie function it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can add cookie helper to autolod -> applications/config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('cookie');
```

if you use autoload you don`t need to load it manualy each time when you need it!

```
$this->load->helper('cookie');
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple

$.cookie('the_cookie');

Answer (score 0):

the issue solved out . i tried to add cookie via jquery which has different encryption from codeigniter. the issue solved out when i tried to using normal $_COOKIE[] . there i eliminated encryption issue.