# how to get select2(plugin) tag value in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 plugin.

I'm able to get the selected tags array in jquery,but how can I append array into the DOM and **get values in php on form submission** or any other methods?

There are multiple file uploads in my form so I don't want ajax.
Here is a tag on which I'm applying `select2`.

```
<input type="hidden" id="tags" value="tag" style="width: 400px;">
```

Here is a fiddle I'm using: http://jsfiddle.net/X6V2s/66/

I have an array of values in jquery but want it in php.

can i append array into DOM(if yes then?how)

How could I accompolish this ?
Please help me.
      Thanks in advance.

Comment: try setting cookies of selected tags before submitting a form , dont forget to remove cookie after form submition. then you can access cookies in php `$_COOKIE('cookie_name');`

Comment: @Noman ok i will try that

Comment: is there any possible way to accomplish using local strorage

Comment: local storage are use for `client-side` for more details read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220660/local-storage-vs-cookies?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: @Noman thanks for your further help

Comment: @Noman make your comment into answer,as it was helpful . i got my solution. i also reffered this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086989/jquery-and-php-cookies

Comment: Please check :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try setting cookies of selected tags before submitting a form.
then you can access cookies in `php`

> NOTE: dont forget to remove cookie after form submition.

**JS:** using [**jQuery Cookie**](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) For further understating about JQuery cookie read [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-do-i-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery)

```
$.cookie("test", 1, {
   expires : 10,           //expires in 10 days

   path    : '/',          //The value of the path attribute of the cookie 
                           //(default: path of page that created the cookie).

   domain  : 'yourdomain.com',  //The value of the domain attribute of the cookie
                           //(default: domain of page that created the cookie).

   secure  : true          //If set to true the secure attribute of the cookie
                           //will be set and the cookie transmission will
                           //require a secure protocol (defaults to false).
});
```

**PHP** Read cookie on server-side.

```
echo $_COOKIE('test');
```